# Is Spring Security Oauth2 with JWT really stateless?

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-security, jwt

I am trying to setup a REST-API with Spring. For securing it I currently play around with Spring Security oAuth2 with JWT tokens. My REST-API application will be AuthorizationServer and ResourceServer both in one.

My problem is now that once generated tokens, are not valid anymore after a restart of my REST-API application. Same when I run 2 instances of it. Tokens that are generated and valid on one of them are not valid on the other.

I figured out that the implementation of the JwtAccessTokenConverter is generating a signingKey/verifierKey randomly on startup. Which of course explains my observations, but leaves me with the question: How can this be stateless?

Please correct me if my thoughts here are wrong, or maybe I missed some important detail. But to me right now this behavior seems to defeat the purpose of JWT.

Comment: Are you sure  that your implementation of JwtAccessTokenConverter is generating a randomly key on startup? Is there no private/public key in your spring config ?

Comment: Thanks for you answer. Yes I am sure. I am using the spring implementation you can find here https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/blob/master/spring-security-oauth2/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/oauth2/provider/token/store/JwtAccessTokenConverter.java You can see on line 81 and 85 how it is generated.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the Answers so far, but I just figured it out myself.

The randomly generated signing/verifier key is just a default that should probably not be used. Unfortunately this is not really documented. 
I now set those keys manually on startup. The result is, that my tokens are valid on all my REST-API instances and also are still valid after a reboot.

I guess the random value is more a "secure default" so that people are not accidentally using the same known key.